# How to forward call from one SIM to second?

Tags: settings, calls, sim, blu-win-hd

I have BLU Win HD LTE Dual SIM. I want to transfer call from one SIM to another.

From this [site](http://cellphoneforums.net/general-cell-phone-forum/t381882-blu-win-hd-lte-forward-calls%3B-block-calls-messages.html#axzz3qXxcFpFD):

> Forward Calls (Unconditional):
>
> On the Start screen, tap “People” From within the app, tap “…”
>   (lower-right corner of the screen) Tap “settings” Enable the switch
>   next to “Call forwarding” Enter the phone number to forward calls to
>   Tap “Save”

But I don't see any "Call forwarding" in Settings.

Is it possible to do forwarding on this phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a typo to me. Instead of the People app, open the Phone app and go to Settings, that's where the call forwarding option is.

For more information, see the [official calling + messaging how-to](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/calling-and-messaging/calling-options).

Comment: okay, found: Phone -> SIM 2 Settings